# How to convert Generator method to an Iterator

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, binary-search-tree, ecmascript-next

I have this recursive generator *method* which yields the values of a BST in ascending order:

```
  *inOrder(node){

    if (node === null) {
      return;
    }

    if(node.left){
      yield * this.inOrder(node.left);
    }

    yield node.val;

    if(node.right){
      yield * this.inOrder(node.right);
    }

  }
```

A recursive generator is quite CPU intensive. I am trying to convert it to an iterator, to better understand what's going on, here is my attempt which is totally incomplete, using an *iterative* solution:

```
  [Symbol.iterator]() {

    // iterative solution?
    const queue = [this.rootNode];

    return {
      next(){

        return {
          done: true,
          value: // (last (right-most) value in tree)
        }

      }
    }

  }
```

I get the feeling an iterative solution to do depth-first search from left-to-right, will require a queue, but not sure. Alternatively, a recursive solution could work where we pass in the root node initially like so:

```
  [Symbol.iterator](node) {

    // recursive solution 
    return {
      next(){

        return {
          done: true,
          value: // (last (right-most) value in tree)
        }

      }
    }

  }
```

However, I am not sure how to implement with an iterator, either an iterative or recursive solution. So that's my question, how to take the generator code and use an iterator instead, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @Sachin's answer and evolved it a bit. This is not well-tested, but appears to work:

```
  [Symbol.iterator]() {

    const stack = [];
    let currentNode = this.rootNode;

    return {
      next() {

        while (currentNode !== null) {
          stack.push(currentNode);
          currentNode = currentNode.left || null;
        }

        if (stack.length < 1) {
          return {done: true, value: null};
        }

        const node = stack.pop();
        currentNode = node.right || null;
        return {done: false, value: node.val};

      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `stack` to store the nodes that need to be visited

Perform a `dfs` of the tree in a left-to-right order.

`next` method is called until all nodes in tree have been visited & iterator is done.

```
   [Symbol.iterator]() {
    const stack = [];
    let currentNode = this.rootNode;

    return {
        next() {
            while (currentNode !== null || stack.length > 0) {
                if (currentNode !== null) {
                    stack.push(currentNode);
                    currentNode = currentNode.left;
                } else {
                    const node = stack.pop();
                    currentNode = node.right;
                    return {
                        done: false,
                        value: node.val
                    };
                }
            }
            return {
                done: true,
                value: undefined
            };
        }
    };
}
```

**Recursive**

```
[Symbol.iterator]() {
  return {
    next: function* (node = this.rootNode) {
      if (node === null) {
        return { done: true };
      }

      yield* this.next(node.left);
      yield node.val;
      yield* this.next(node.right);
    }.bind(this)
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks, I wonder if there is a way to do a recursive solution where you pass the node to `next()` like `next(node)`? Although iterative solution is generally better.

Comment: also, if you use `const stack = [this.rootNode];` can you get rid of the check for `while(currentNode !== null) || ...` and just use `while(stack.length >0`?

Comment: there is a bug in this code tmk, when using `for..of` it gets through the whole list, and then starts at 0.5 and goes up again?

Comment: add a flag to the iterator indicating whether or not all values have been returned. You can set this flag to `true` when the `next` method returns the final value in the tree.

Comment: sorry I don't see how that flag would work, can you update your answer?

Comment: I added an answer, I pivoted off your answer, if you could test mine, that'd be cool!

Comment: the problem was the  combined condition of `while (currentNode !== null || stack.length > 0) {` is very hard to understand, so I wrote one without that condition (which I hope works).

Answer (score 2):

With your data structure `{left, val, right}` you cannot avoid recursion (or a stack) if you want to traverse all nodes in inorder (`left`, then `val`, then `right`, what you call ascending order). And the `*inOrder` generator function does this perfectly. It can also be used to make the BST class an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator):

```js
class BST {
  constructor(root) {
    this[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
      return this.inOrder(root);
    }
  }
  * inOrder(node) {...}
}
```

Traversal without recursion is possible if you use a richer data structure, for example the "threaded representation" explained in Knuth, The Art Of Computer Programming [taocp](/questions/tagged/taocp), section 2.3.1. In this representation, *every* node has a left link and a right link, and those that do not point to a child are called "threads", which point to the predecessor or successor node instead. Setting up these extra threads in the constructor (and updating them whenever a node is inserted or deleted) is extra work, but the iterator is then simplified to:

```js
*[Symbol.iterator]() {
  var node = this.root;
  while (node.left && !node.leftThread) node = node.left;
  yield node.val;
  while (node) {
    var next = node.right;
    if (!node.rightThread)
      while (!next.leftThread) next = next.left;
    if (next) yield next.val;
    node = next;
  }
}
```

(This is just one example, there are doubtless many other data structures for trees.)

Whether the extra work with the extra data structure pays off depends on what happens more often to the tree: traversals or updates.

Comment: whats wrong with braces? :)

Comment: on that subject, I don't see why `node` would always be defined here `yield node.val;`, can you correct that? couldn't node be undefined there?

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do a recursive solution where you pass the node to next() like next(node)? Although iterative solution is generally better.

Comment: The `while` condition ensures that `node !== undefined`.

Comment: thanks what do you think of my answer

Comment: Looks good if you want to use a stack.